# ObjectInputStream#readObject throws java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, sockets

I am getting a `java.io.EOFException` while trying to send data (It could be seen as a kind of POST although I am not using http) from a client back to the server.

My client source code:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverIpAddr, IConstant.ServerPort);
OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
out.write(dataByteArray);
out.flush();
if(out!=null)
    out.close();
if(clientSocket!=null)
    clientSocket.close();
```

My server source code :

```
try{    
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(IConstant.ServerPort);
      while(true)
      {
           Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
           ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
           Object obj = ois.readObject();
           byte[] bytes = (byte[])obj;
           System.out.println("A notification has been received");
           //process bytes
           //...
       }
} catch(IOException ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();  
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this how I build my `dataByteArray` object (where `PlayList` is a POJO that implements java.io.Serializable) :

```
private byte[] serializePlayList(PlayList playList) throws IOException{
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        ObjectOutput out = null;
        try {
          out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
          out.writeObject(playList);
          out.flush();
          byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
        } finally {
          try {
            bos.close();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
          }
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Whenever the server tries to perform `ois.readObject()`, a `java.io.EOFException` is thrown. Could anyone please explain why?

Comment: You're writing to a plain output stream, but reading from an object input stream. Why not write to an object output stream? Or, how do you build `dataByteArray` so as to ensure it's a whole object graph?

Comment: @Andy : I have updated my thread and added the method used to build the dataByteArray object

Comment: Are you sure the client is writing the array, not throwing an exception?

Comment: If the Read is crashing it is because the problem is what it is sent to it

Comment: I have actually tried to use a String instead of dataByteArray, the problem persists. I guess then that this has nothing to do with data sent but rather the way the connection is managed. Did I miss something or added something not right in my source code?

Comment: Stack trace please, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should send `playList` in `Object`:

Client:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverIpAddr, IConstant.ServerPort);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream();
out.writeObject(playlist);
```

Server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(IConstant.ServerPort);
Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
PlayList playList = (PlayList) ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can using thread and get to start thread ,  the thread in spatial class

like this :

```
public class receive  extends Thread{
public   Socket socket = null;
ObjectInputStream din = null;
data_socket respon = null ;
data_socket dtsk = new data_socket();

public receive(Socket skt) {
        this.socket=skt;

     }
@Override
public void run(){
    try {

        din = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
        while(true){

                respon=(data_socket)din.readObject();

            switch(respon.action){
                case "login"             : this.check_login(); break;
                case "afeef"             : this.afeef();break;

                default                  : System.out.println("unknow action");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::ERROR 1::::::::::::::::"+ex.toString());
        System.out.println("You r Lost connect to server ");
       System.exit(0);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::ERROR 2::::::::::::::::"+e.getException());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I am getting a `java.io.EOFException` while trying to send data

No you aren't. You're getting it while trying to *receive* data.

Your sending code doesn't make sense. You should just serialize the `PlayList` object directly to an existing `ObjectOutputStream`, rather than all these shenanigans with `ByteArrayOutputStreams` and a new object stream per send.

And you should therefore also cast the result of `readObject()` directly to `PlayList`.

And the reading code should loop until `EOFException` has been caught, which means the peer closed the connection.

NB `clientSocket` and `out` cannot possibly be null at the points you are testing them.